# Can't install beautifulsoup and requests on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I downloaded python 3.8 32 bits for windows 7 and now I'm trying to install the necessary packages. However, I get :

```
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautiful... / request... from versions: none
ERROR: No matching distributing found for requests-2.22.0 (same for beautifulsoup)
```

I even updated pip by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` but didn't work either.

[image: A schreenshot]

Am I missing something? Python is installed on:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pythonw.exe. 
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```

And the packages are on: `C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\TATOEBA\Python`

Comment: Try `pip install beautifulsoup4` (without the version). Same for `requests`. If you want to specify a version number, then `requests==2.20.0`.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of pip install beautifulsoup4-4.8.2, try this one,

```
pip install beautifulsoup4

pip install requests
```

I think, there is problem with syntax, you are writing.

```
pip install <package_name>== <version>
```

is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If Saurabh Kansal answer don't fix the problem, just in case try to pip3 install beautifulsoup4